# How to change the font size in the Properties window in Visual Studio IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide, font-size, propertygrid

We can change font for VS IDE items in the Options\Environments\Fonts and Colors dialog. However, I still cannot find how to do that for the Properties pane. Can anybody help me with that?

Working mainly with VS 2013 Professional or Community Editions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `> tools > options > Fonts and Colors`  (Show settings drop down) 
Environment font for menus etc
Locals Window for properties window

Comment: I just see the 'Environment Font' setting. Is it what you wrote?

Comment: Oh, yes - it works! The problem is that it is not applied to the Property Grid immediately like for other VS items (menus, tab headers, etc). We need to restart VS to see the effect.

Comment: This looked like the answer for my problem, but still have an issue. I never changed the Font size for the properties and locals windows in Visual Studio 2019. Something happened and those 2 windows Font size now huge. I tried changing in options and Font size is 9 like everything else. Tried resetting to default and restarting with no luck.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must restart the IDE to make the properties window changes